# Sharing apps in different countries via Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Imagine I have one application.
Is it possible to share with Google Play this with the same name by making the necessary language changes in both Europe and the USA?

Actually, can you briefly describe the way to do this?
or sharing a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can share your app with the same name around the world. Here is a demonstration of making available your app in 173 different countries.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I actually realized that if I continue the process, I can see